# ¿Se podría añadir una opción para cerrar una pregunta por "tarea escolar"?

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Veo que hay muchas preguntas en las que el OP simplemente se limita a indicar el enunciado de su tarea y no se ve ningún esfuerzo por su parte.

Aquí un ejemplo bien claro: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36259/alguien-sabr%C3%ADa-resolver-este-ejercicio

Copio aquí la pregunta por si la pregunta acaba eliminada que esta pregunta no carezca de sentido:

> 2.- Introducida una cadena, con n palabras, realizar un programa JAVA que visualice una estadística de las palabras contenidas en la cadena. Por simplicidad admitiremos que no se introducirán palabras menores de 3 letras, ni mayores de 7 y que entre palabra y palabra hay un blanco (excepto la palabra final).
>
> Así, si se introduce la cadena: “rosa jazmin clavel Boj dalia lis girasol Ajo tulipan ANIS”
>
> Se visualizaría lo siguiente:
>
> Palabras de 3 letras: 3
>
> No se me ocurre como puedo contar o visualizar las palabras que contengan 3 letras

El OP no añade nada de código, nada de pseudocódigo ni un mero indicio de haberse esforzado en su tarea. Queda claramente que es una tarea, incluso me apostaría que el número 2.- que añade justo antes del enunciado es el número del ejercicio. Es decir, copio y pego el enunciado aquí y me limito a que me den la respuesta.

Independientemente de que sea una pregunta no aceptable desde mi punto de vista, lo cual no voy a discutir aquí, normalmente este tipo de preguntas se cierran como "muy amplias".

Creo que sería mucho más descriptivo para el OP poder cerrar su pregunta como tema "no relacionado porque..." con la siguiente descripción:

> La tarea se basa en una tarea escolar sin ningún indicio de esfuerzo por parte del usuario que pregunta. Para poder reabrir la pregunta deberá indicar el esfuerzo realizado para la resolución del ejercicio.

Se que se un poco largo pero no se me ocurre ninguna otra manera de acortarlo introduciendo todos los puntos necesarios.

**ACLARACIÓN:** Este tipo de cierre se aplicaría SOLAMENTE a preguntas en las que el usuario que pregunta no muestra ningún tipo de esfuerzo y simplemente copia el enunciado. **No se aplicaría** para respuestas que, aunque muestran el enunciado, también muestran el esfuerzo que han realizado mediante código, explicación o algún otro medio.

¿Qué opináis? ¿Se debería añadir esta opción de cierre?

Comment: Es muy subjetivo... la aclaración que haces muestra la subjetividad. ¿Cómo impedirías que alguien la use en cualquier otro caso? Afortunadamente en esto de las tareas, el criterio es bastante común, por lo que la opción que propones más que una nueva causa es un atajo que nos ahorraría teclear todo el choro de que "aquí no hacemos tareas", "demuestra tu esfuerzo", "enséñale a pescar a un hombre", etc. VOTO A FAVOR DEL ATAJO.

Comment: @toledano Sí, pero es el mismo criterio que por ejemplo si alguien marca como duplicada una pregunta de otra aunque sean totalmente distintas. Puede realizarlo cualquiera. Sin embargo, por norma general y por sentido común, la gente no lo realiza. Y sí, es un atajo al igual que se ha implementado el atajo de marcar que una pregunta está en inglés, aunque he etiquetado la pregunta como `característica-nueva` ya que no he encontrado otra forma de realizarlo.

Comment: El problema es que lo que propones no se puede controlar. Mira, a los nuevos les piden que lean el recorrido y hasta les dan una medallita, ¿cierto? ¿Eso asegura la lectura? ¿La lectura asegura la comprensión? Lo mismo pasa con tu propuesta, si alguien quiere usar esa opción la usará y si no la quiere usar, no la usará. Y más aún, ¿qué puedes hacer usar si la usan mal, por ejemplo, si no siguen el ejemplo de tu aclaración? ¿Qué harías si se usa esa opción cuando la pregunta está bien?  Tu propuesta no puede dirigirse a normar la conducta de la comunidad, solo a facilitarnos ciertas tareas.

Comment: @toledano En ningún momento he dicho que sea para normar la conducta de la comunidad (o al menos no era mi intención). Simplemente quería saber si era posible implementar este atajo al igual que se introdujo el atajo de cerrar una pregunta porque estaba en inglés. Por supuesto, depende de la conciencia de cada uno usarlo bien o mal, eso evidentemente no se puede controlar.

Comment: lee por favor el párrafo que empieza con la palabra __ACLARACIÓN__. ¿La opción aparecería _automágicamente_ cuando el editor detecte que no hay ningún tipo de esfuerzo? ¿Eso lo puede hacer StackOverflow? Te sugiero que modifiques tu propuesta y tu aclaración se convierta en sugerencia de uso, una guía de mejores prácticas o algo si: "Propongo que se aplique, cuando el usuario que propone el cierre considere que la publicación no muestra ningún esfuerzo o cuando en su opinión solo se ha copiado el enunciado de la tarea, en otros casos, el usuario podría considerar las demás opciones".

Comment: @toledano Sé lo que he escrito y creo que en ninguna parte indico que va a aparecer _automágicamente_(?) en ninguna parte. "Este tipo de cierre **se aplicaría** SOLAMENTE a preguntas en las que el usuario que pregunta no muestra ningún tipo de esfuerzo y simplemente copia el enunciado." Cuando pongo esta frase es relativa al uso que los usuarios deberían de hacer con él, no a que Stackoverflow automáticamente detecte que en una pregunta se ha escrito un enunciado de una tarea escolar.

Comment: Ok. Comprendo. Tienes razón. Apoyo tu propuesta.

Comment: @toledano La mejor forma de que se vea que esta pregunta tiene apoyo creo que es dándole upvote. De esta manera el resto podrá ver que tiene aceptación por la comunidad. Además, aquí no se ganan puntos así que no influye en nada en el día a día de la reputación. Gracias! :)

Comment: Yo pienso que la opción "demasiado amplia" es explícita. Estuve intentando escribir una respuesta pero lo que dice allí es suficiente.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sin embargo, el hecho de que sea "demasiado amplia" puede ser porque pregunta sobre el origen del universo o sobre como pelar patatas con un pelapatatas. Creo que hay algunas más amplias que otras y el que tengan un enunciado definido realmente creo que las diferencia del resto debido a que normalmente limita su contenido. Sería como un atajo para las preguntas que claramente se ven como tareas escolares. Y respecto al resto de preguntas "muy amplias" creo que estas son muy fáciles de diferenciar.

Comment: Si es sobre el origen del universo o sobre cómo pelar patatas con un pelapatatas, son de tipo "no relacionado". Pero sobre tu punto, no solo aplica a preguntas tipo tarea, sino a preguntas tipo "asme el travaxo pliz". Todas esas preguntas simplemente son "demasiado amplias". ¿Por qué? Porque *"existen muchas respuestas posibles, o las buenas respuestas son demasiado extensas para este formato. Añade **detalles** para reducir el conjunto de respuestas o separar un problema que se puede responder en pocos párrafos."*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Bueno, realmente puse lo del universo y el pelapatatas como ejemplo de exageración (como si los estrapolasemos a la programación), no porque se pudieran o no postear aquí. Y realmente por eso puse la pregunta, para que la comunidad decida sobre si se debería o les gustaría que se añadiera esta opción. Realmente a mí me resulta mucho más contextual que simplemente poner "demasiado amplia". Y no digo que haya que hacer una opción para cada tipo de pregunta "demasiado amplia", simplemente que estas predominan sobre las demás.

Comment: Sigo pensando que esto aplica a las preguntas tipo "¡hacedme el trabajo por favor!", que vienen en dos formas: 1) tareas/ejercicios de clase, 2) algo que debo hacer en el trabajo/proyecto personal. Los dos cumplen el mismo patrón: <saludo> <enunciado del trabajo> <mensaje de agradecimiento> <desconectarse y volver luego de varias horas a ver si ya puedo copiar/pegar>. De ser así, creo que si se crease un motivo de cierre, podría tener una descripción más concisa al respecto, de preferencia que evite mencionar negaciones.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sí, ahora que lo dices también se podría aplicar a más casos y no solamente a la realización de tareas. Yo lo puse porque es lo más característico y se nota mucho cuando ponen un enunciado directamente copiado del libro de texto. Por supuesto el mensaje que he indicado en la pregunta es simplemente lo que se me ocurrió a mí como orientación pero por supuesto no es que quisiera que fuera así, si no que los usuarios también sugirieran sus propios mensajes (añadir/quitar algo).

Comment: Pues la verdad, como puse en mi primer comentario, al pensar en una descripción para este motivo de cierre y ver el de "demasiado amplia", la descripción del segundo es suficiente al respecto. Quizás podrías crear una nueva propuesta tomando la de "demasiado amplia" como base. Cabe resaltar que **las descripciones de motivo de cierre buscan la conciliación**, por ello se escriben de manera amigable y sin atacar p.e. cuando leo "sin ningún indicio de esfuerzo", en realidad no sabemos si se esforzó o no. Muchas veces he visto que el OP sí se esforzó pero se avergonzaba de mostrar su trabajo.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Tienes razón. Igual si que es demasiado incisiva. Le doy una vuelta e intento modificar el mensaje para que no quede tan acusadora.

Answer (score 5):

Yo lo cerraría en el caso de que simplemente copien el enunciado y no hayan ni intentado nada, pero en el caso de que busquen ayuda después de haberlo intentado varias veces y estén como volviéndose locos pegando las mil soluciones que intentaron, no. ¿Debería haber opción de cierre por esta opción? Si, pero usarla con cabeza para según que casos específicos.

Comment: Justo estaba editando mi pregunta para añadir una aclaración que hace incapié en esto.

Comment: Nada! Yo voto porque sí haya una opción para que este tipo de temas se puedan cerrar a criterio del moderador.

Answer (score -3):

Personalmente usaría la intervención del moderador<sup>1</sup>;

> **Se necesita la intervención de un moderador**: *Un problema que no está en la lista anterior y que requiere de la intervención de un moderador. ¡Sé específico y detallado!*

---

<sup>1</sup> Solo cuando la pregunta pueda provenir de un usuario que insiste en generar preguntas de tipo "tarea".

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo. La intervención de un moderador es para casos puntuales que la comunidad no pueda gestionar por sí sola. Todo aquello que se pueda especificar en los motivos es más práctico que llamar la atención a dos personas que ya tienen suficiente tarea. Para que intervengan los moderadores ya tenemos la opción _reportar_.